# Jekyll _config.yml set variable to dynamic value

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

In `_config.yml` I'm trying to do:

```
url: "/" + github.repository_name
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can! Just not in the exact way you were wondering.

The YAML is static, so you can't modify that, but you *can* use `site.github` metadata in your Liquid templates:

```
<a href="{{ site.github.url }}"> SITE HOME </a>
```

---

**Extra info**: GitHub provides a lot of variables on their page build [here](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-metadata-on-github-pages/#available-repository-metadata):

> The following sample information is exposed to Jekyll templates in the
>   site.github namespace:
>
> ```
> {
>     "versions": {
>         "jekyll": "1.5.1",
>         "kramdown": "1.3.1",
>         "liquid": "2.5.5",
>         "maruku": "0.7.0",
>         "rdiscount": "2.1.7",
>         "redcarpet": "2.3.0",
>         "RedCloth": "4.2.9",
>         "jemoji": "0.1.0",
>         "jekyll-mentions": "0.0.6",
>         "jekyll-redirect-from": "0.3.1",
>         "jekyll-sitemap": "0.2.0",
>         "github-pages": "18",
>         "ruby": "2.1.1"
>     },
>     "hostname": "github.com",
>     "pages_hostname": "github.io",
>     "api_url": "https://api.github.com",
>     "environment": "dotcom",
>     "public_repositories": [ Repository Objects ],
>     "organization_members": [ User Objects ],
>     "build_revision": "cbd866ebf142088896cbe71422b949de7f864bce",
>     "project_title": "metadata-example",
>     "project_tagline": "A GitHub Pages site to showcase repository metadata",
>     "owner_name": "github",
>     "owner_url": "https://github.com/github",
>     "owner_gravatar_url": "https://github.com/github.png",
>     "repository_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example",
>     "repository_nwo": "github/metadata-example",
>     "repository_name": "metadata-example",
>     "zip_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example/zipball/gh-pages",
>     "tar_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example/tarball/gh-pages",
>     "clone_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example.git",
>     "releases_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example/releases",
>     "issues_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example/issues",
>     "wiki_url": "https://github.com/github/metadata-example/wiki",
>     "language": null,
>     "is_user_page": false,
>     "is_project_page": true,
>     "show_downloads": true,
>     "url": "http://username.github.io/metadata-example", // (or the CNAME)
>     "contributors": [ User Objects ],
>     "releases": [ Release Objects ]
>
> }
> ```